# How Can I Align Multiple Lines on a Right Bracket?

Tags: align

I am trying to align 2 equations on a right bracket enviroment. Below is my code and enviroment for Right Cases/Brackets

```
\documentclass{report}

\newenvironment{rcases}
    {\left.\begin{aligned}}
    {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}

        \begin{align*}
            \begin{rcases}
                +:\, & \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longmapsto \mathbb{N} \\
                & (x, y) \longmapsto x + y 
            \end{rcases}
            && + \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \\
            && + = \{ (x, y) \,|\, x, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to get

```
&& + \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \\
&& + = \{ (x, y) \,|\, x, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq
```

on the same line or to the same level on the right bracket.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

What happens is that the part

```
& + \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
\\
& + = \{ (x, y) \,|\, x, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq
```

Is treated by `align*` as two different lines. What you want `align*` to do is treat it as one symbol, which you can do by nesting `aligned` inside `align*` environment. You can think of it as illustrated here

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\newenvironment{rcases}
    {\left.\begin{aligned}}
    {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
    \begin{rcases}
        +:\, & \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longmapsto \mathbb{N}
    \\
        & (x, y) \longmapsto x + y 
    \end{rcases}
    \quad
    \begin{aligned}
        & + \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
    \\
        & + = \{ (x, y) \,|\, x, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But I need those 2 things aligned left, not right

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Mind explaining what you did here so I can understand it better (As I am a newbie in TeX)

Answer (score 0):

The `rcases` environment is already defined by `mathtools` (which extends `amsmath`). I propose to use the `alignat`environment, which gives you full control on the spacing between the two groups of alignment:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \begin{rcases}
        \begin{aligned}
        +:\, & \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longmapsto \mathbb{N}
        \\
        & (x, y) \longmapsto x + y \strut
        \end{aligned}
    \end{rcases}
 & \qquad &
        \begin{aligned}
       & + \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
        \\
        & + = \{ (x, y) \,|\, x, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \strut
        \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]